# onActivityResult: Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to setup google sign in in my login activity but I got this error on onActivityResult

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9001, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }}
```

I check and try many solutions for this error which posted on other questions but it didn't help at all!

here how I use it in my activity class

```
private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
        .requestEmail()
        .build()

    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

startActivityForResult(googleSignInClient.signInIntent!!, RC_SIGN_IN)
```

here is on activity result

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode!=RESULT_CANCELED){
            if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && data!=null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult $mPresenter : $requestCode : $resultCode : $data")
                mPresenter!!.result(requestCode, resultCode, data) // line of the error 73 

            }
        }
    }
```

here the full logcat for the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.googlemvp.signin, PID: 11583
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=9001, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.googlemvp.signin/com.googlemvp.signin.ui.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4846)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4887)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at c.d.a.a.a.d.a(:66)
        at c.d.a.a.a.e.f(:34)
        at com.googlemvp.signin.ui.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(:73)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4839)
```

here the data in the onActivityResult in log it's not null at all

```
LoginActivity: onActivityResult c.d.a.a.a.e@97eb6e3 : 9001 : -1 : Intent { (has extras) }
```

here the result method  in presenter and attached method in interactor class

```
// in presenter class 
 override fun result(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        mInteractor!!.performResult(requestCode, resultCode,data)
    }

 // in interactor class 
 override fun performResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                mListener!!.onStart(account.idToken!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                mListener!!.onFailure(e)
               // Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: your presenter is null, make sure that it is initialized or call `mPresenter?.let{it.result(requestCode, resultCode, data) )`

Comment: I printed the presenter object in log it's not null any way I found the error from this part account.idToken --> it was null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you should not use `!!` in your code. The double exclamation was chosen to scream at you, like in `don't use it!!`. When you use `!!` you are basically disabling one of the nicest Kotlin features - null safety.

But in your case this is not the root of your problem.

As we can see in the log you have an instance of the mPresenter referenced as `c.d.a.a.a.e@97eb6e3`

Then in the crash log we see

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at c.d.a.a.a.d.a(:66)
        at c.d.a.a.a.e.f(:34)
        at com.googlemvp.signin.ui.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(:73)
```

Notice that the call log goes from bottom to top and from your activity line 73 we go inside the `mPresenter` line 34 and then to some other class `c.d.a.a.a.d.a` line 66 where the actual `NullPointerException` happens.
You should follow this log and fix the null problem in that third class.

Comment: thanks too much this helps me
I found the error in this part               mListener!!.onStart(account.idToken!!) because account id token is null